# Help with an tricky inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I am struggling to prove that

$$\frac{1}{N}(\exp(x)-1) > (\exp\left(\frac{x}{N}\right)-1)$$ 
where $x>0, N >1$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
e^{x/N}-1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k!}\frac{x^k}{N^k}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k!}\frac{x^k}{N}=\frac{e^x-1}{N}
$$

Answer (score 8):

Let $t=e^{x/N}>1$.

You want to prove

$$\frac{t^N-1}N>t-1.$$

We have

$$\frac{t^N-1}{t-1}=t^{N-1}+t^{N-2}+\cdots1>N,$$ as there are $N$ terms.

---

Alternatively, for $t=1$,

$$t^N-1=N(t-1)$$ and when we differentiate, for $t>1$,

$$Nt^{N-1}>N$$ so that the LHS grows faster.

---

Alternatively, by the Binomial theorem, with $t=1+u$,

$$t^N-1=(1+u)^N-1=Nu+\frac{N(N-1)}2u^2+\cdots>Nu=N(t-1)$$ as all terms are positive.

Comment: You probably mean *differentiate*, not *derive*.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: yes I do. (Though I don't mean *distinguish* :)

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)$ be defined as

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{N}-(e^{x/N}-1)$$

Note that $f(0)=0$.  Then, note that

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{N}\left(e^x-e^{x/N}\right)$$

When $x>0$ and $N> 1$, $f'(x)>0$.  Therefore, $f(x)$ is increasing for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.  Therefore, the mean-value theorem guarantees that $f(x)> 0$ for $x>0$.  And we are done!

Answer (score 3):

Because $\exp$ is convex and nonlinear, [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) gives
$$
\frac{\exp(x)}{N}+\underbrace{\frac{\exp(0)}{N}+\cdots+\frac{\exp(0)}{N}}_{N-1\text{ times}}>\exp\left(\frac{x+0+\cdots+0}{N}\right)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\exp(x)}{N}+\frac{N-1}{N}>\exp(x/N)\iff\frac{\exp(x)-1}{N}>\exp(x/N)-1.
$$

Comment: This feels a bit like you "killed a fly with a sledgehammer", but it's certainly elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this only because the second derivative test gives an alternative (but certainly not the most elegant) approach. Define
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{N}e^x - \frac{1}{N} - e^{x/N}+1$$
This function has one critical point, at which 
$$\frac{1}{N} e^x = \frac{1}{N}e^{x/N} \quad \Rightarrow \quad x=0$$
If $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $N>1$, then one can easily verify that 
$$f''(0) = \frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N^2}>0$$
meaning this function has a minimum at $x=0$, and $f(0)>0$ under the current assumptions.